# Sum totals of timestamp

Tags: oracle, sum, timestamp, ora-00932

I have the following query to calculate the summation timestamp

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_SPENT) FROM
(
 select a - b as time_spent from tbl1 where name = 'xxx'
 union all
select c - d as time_spent from tbl2 where name= 'yyy'
)a;
```

The sub-query return result as
+00 00:01:54.252000
But the entire query return error as ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND.

Understand it required something like this

```
SELECT COALESCE (
(to_timestamp('2014-09-22 16:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS') - to_timestamp('2014-09-22 09:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')) -
(to_timestamp('2014-09-22 16:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS') - to_timestamp('2014-09-22 09:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')), INTERVAL '0' DAY) FROM DUAL;
```

How can achieve along with sub-queries that retrieve data from Timestamp type columns?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot sum `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` in Oracle. I think this is one of the top rated open feature request.

You can cast the `TIMESTAMP` into `DATE` values, then the result is the difference in days. Multiply by `24*60*60` is you like to get seconds instead:

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_SPENT) * 24*60*60 FROM FROM
(
 select CAST(a AS DATE) - CAST(b AS DATE) as time_spent from tbl1 where name = 'xxx'
 union all
select CAST(d AS DATE) - CAST(d AS DATE) as time_spent from tbl2 where name= 'yyy'
);
```

Or you can write a function which converts `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` into seconds:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetSeconds(ds INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND) DETERMINISTIC RETURN NUMBER AS
BEGIN
    RETURN EXTRACT(DAY FROM ds)*24*60*60 
        + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ds)*60*60 
        + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ds)*60 
        + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ds);
END;
```

and use it like this:

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_SPENT), numtodsinterval(SUM(TIME_SPENT), 'second')
(
 select GetSeconds(a-b) as time_spent from tbl1 where name = 'xxx'
 union all
select GetSeconds(c-d) as time_spent from tbl2 where name= 'yyy'
);
```

Comment: that's great :) the CAST into DATE work perfectly together with sum () * 24*60*60

Answer (score 0):

try using below query

```
 SELECT sum(extract(second from time_spent)) FROM
 (
  select a - b as time_spent from test2 where name = 'xxx'
  union all
  select c - d as time_spent from tbl2 where name= 'yyy'
 )a;
```

Looks like time_spent column is timestamp type in your table an d it is not able to pass the correct data type in Sum function. Use extract function to get Seconds from time_spent.

Comment: This works only if the difference is less than a Minute.

Comment: yeah, i did a manual calculation,it's not accurate as compared to @WernfriedDomscheit 's solution

Answer (score 0):

```sql
with t(a,b) as (
  select timestamp'2014-09-22 16:00:00.000', timestamp'2014-09-23 16:00:00.001' from dual union all
  select timestamp'2014-09-22 16:00:00.000', timestamp'2014-09-24 16:00:00.001' from dual union all
  select timestamp'2014-09-22 16:00:00.000', timestamp'2014-09-25 16:00:00.001' from dual union all
  select timestamp'2014-09-22 16:00:00.000', timestamp'2014-09-26 16:00:00.001' from dual union all
  select timestamp'2014-09-22 16:00:00.000', timestamp'2014-09-27 16:00:00.001' from dual
)
select
                        sum( (date'1-1-1'+(b-a)*24*60*60 - date'1-1-1'))     as ssum_seconds_1,
                  round(sum( (date'1-1-1'+(b-a)*24*60*60 - date'1-1-1')), 3) as ssum_seconds_rounded,
 numtodsinterval( round(sum( (date'1-1-1'+(b-a)*24*60*60 - date'1-1-1')), 3), 'second') dsint
from t
/
```

Comment: @wernfried Read my example more carefully: I showed how to sum intervals

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit my answer shows how to do it... What have you tried to say in your comments?